# Trying to make "span" tag read-only in text editor in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox

I have a rather peculiar issue with the way  tag is handled in Firefox. I currently have a Richfaces component , which is a tinyMCE object and HTML is what's expected to be its content. But what I usually have there is a simple text, mixed with what I call "placeholders". These "placeholders" are read-only  objects that the user cannot change, he can only delete them (and only with one click of a backspace or a delete key). So, in the end, that's what the sample might look like:

```
  This is the text that contains info about a certain 
  person, <span contenteditable="false" style="color: grey; font-weight: bold;" class="placeholder ui-draggable" unselectable="ON">[Person Name]</span>, 
  and will be updated further down the road.
```

In IE it works fine, but when it comes to Firefox - the  object becomes editable and selectable, which kind of defeats the purpose of having it there. I was able to make it at least non-selectable, using "-moz-user-select:none;" style attribute, but the user can still edit it (like partially delete it, using backspace key) and it still doesn't work on Safari. It almost seems like  attributes "contenteditable" and "unselectable" don't even work on non-IE browsers.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix that? I'm slowly running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That style tag has no closing quote.

Comment: Sorry about that, just a typo.

Comment: I think this has already been answered by someone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589483/how-to-make-editable-span-in-fire-fox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522848/contenteditable-false-inside-contenteditable-true-block-is-still-editable-in-ie8 Hope these will answer to your query. :)